# How can I use an external js file for my popcorn.js script?

Tags: javascript, popcornjs

So it works perfectly when it's inline between  tags, but how can I put this in an external js file and have it run? I copied it verbatim and it won't work. What's the issue?

edit: you can see the tutorial I'm working off of here: http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-101

code:

```
// ensure the web page (DOM) has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

 // Create a popcorn instance by calling Popcorn("#id-of-my-video")
 var pop_Stephen = Popcorn("#vid_Stephen");

 // add a footnote at 2 seconds, and remove it at 6 seconds
 pop_Stephen.footnote({
   start: 2,
   end: 6,
   text: "Pop!",
   target: "pop"
 });

 // play the video right away
 // pop_Stephen.play();

}, false);
```

edit: OK it seems that it just doesn't work within CODA2, which is a bummer. Any idea why this is?

Comment: It's a general question, not dependent on my specific code.

Comment: Well, generally, it will work, so it's probably something you overlooked. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: I literally cut and pasted the code from within script tags, as mentioned, so it's not something I've overlooked, it's something that does not work in an intuitive manner and I would love to know how to get get it done.

Comment: Yes, and that will (and does) work... If you could just post your current code, we can figure out why it doesn't for you.

Comment: You're missing the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",` opening and closing lines.

Comment: doesn't make a difference, tried it both ways

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19031/discussion-between-sachleen-and-prismspecs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that your `<script />` tags have you loading your external file before the Popcorn library.

Make sure you load 
`<script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>` 
before your external file.

Comment: Maybe something to do with running it on localhost and crossdomain restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the Utility Method Popcorn.getScript?

http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/utility-methods/#Popcorn.getScript

from the site:

```
Popcorn.getScript("yourscript.js");
```

Comment: A link is not a good answer because it can become dead. Can you explain your answer?